# Is this java FFT function complete?

Tags: java, android, fft

I'm using the FFT Library over at

https://code.google.com/p/audio-analyzer-for-android/source/browse/fftLibrary/src/com/google/corp/productivity/specialprojects/android/fft/RealDoubleFFT.java?r=782834ed0be5d47a23df4e6609ef9401fad58e95

My code runs as follows:

```
int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(44100,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(
                    MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT, 44100,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);

short[] buffer = new short[blockSize];
double[] toTransform = new double[blockSize];

audioRecord.startRecording();

while (started) {
   int bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, blockSize);
   for (int i = 0; i < blockSize && i < bufferReadResult; i++) {
       toTransform[i] = (double) buffer[i] / 22050; // signed 16 bit
   }
   transformer.ft(toTransform);
}

audioRecord.stop();
```

I do get a result which is valid but the problem is the output frequency's amplitude oscillates clearly in some kind of sine wave like way, which is a bit strange as it should be constant.

I'm aware FFTs usually have complex parts but the above library just gives a real value back. Is this FFT library suitable to use or am I missing something?

Comment: According to the comments in that code, the `ft` method is real-in, complex-out.

Comment: Suitable for what? You haven't really said what you are trying to do.

Comment: Im trying to get the frequency standouts in the sound given in

Comment: @ronnied How do I access the complex bits out? I can only see real data as output

Comment: Just reading the comments of that Java source, it seems as though if n = even, the imaginary parts = 0.

Comment: Perhaps you need to find a more suitable FFT implementation if you are after the phase components also (the imaginary part [cos] will yield the phase). Most of the time the 'real' [sin] part that yields amplitude is all that is needed.

Comment: @ronnied Thats what I'm confused about. If I leave the imaginary part would I get these Sinusoidal like Oscillations in amplitude over time? Presumably maybe from the shifting phase over time? Or is this just noise/distortion/error? If so would the imaginary part help fix this up?

Comment: The oscillation sounds like a fault. Negating the phase should not suddenly give you a fluctuating amplitude. I'd get a known stable input (file) as the source and if the problem persists, use another FFT implementation. Sounds like you want to use the phase anyway?

Comment: @ronnied: It is not correct that "the imaginary part yields the phase" and that "the real part yields amplitude".

Comment: @ronnied: as Oli says, this is incorrect - `magnitude = sqrt(re^2+im^2)`, `phase = atan2(im, re)`